# How to calculate this entropy $H(X)=H(Y)+(p_{m-1}+p_{m})\cdot H(\frac{p_{m-1}}{p_{m-1}+p_{m}},\frac{p_{m}}{p_{m-1}+p_{m}})$

Tags: probability, information-theory, entropy

I'm given two random variables X and Y such that, [image]

Meaning that X and Y have the same distribution up to $1,...,m-2$.

I'm trying to show that $H(X)=H(Y)+(p_{m-1}+p_{m})\cdot H(\frac{p_{m-1}}{p_{m-1}+p_{m}},\frac{p_{m}}{p_{m-1}+p_{m}})$.

I can see that up to $m-2$ I will have $H(Y)+p_{m-1}log(\frac{1}{p_{m-1}})+p_{m}log(\frac{1}{p_{m}})$ from here I can't figure a way out to factor and reach my goal.

Comment: $H(X)=H(Y)-p_m \log(p_m)-p_{m-1}\log(p_{m-1})+(p_{m-1}+p_{m})\log(p_{m-1}+p_m)$

Comment: Is this the entropy that is written can you expand a bit please?

Comment: This equation follows directly from the definitions of $H(X)$ and $H(Y)$. You should be able to show what you want after that by straightforward algebra

Comment: Yes I understood how you got that ,but i'm still having trouble with the algebra I have got this far with it $H(X)=H(Y)+p_{m-1}log(\frac{p_{m-1}+p_{m}}{p_{m-1}})+p_{m}log(\frac{p_{m-1}+p_{m}}{p_{m}})$

Comment: multiply and divide the last two terms by $(p_{m-1}+p_m)$ and you are done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reached an answer thanks to  @Stelios.

$$H(X)=H(Y)+p_{m-1}log(\frac{p_{m-1}+p_{m}}{p_{m-1}})+p_{m}log(\frac{p_{m-1}+p_{m}}{p_{m}})=H(Y)+(P_{m-1}+p_m)\cdot(\frac{p_{m-1}}{p_{m-1}+p_{m}}log(\frac{p_{m-1}+p_{m}}{p_{m-1}})+\frac{p_{m}}{p_{m-1}+p_{m}}log(\frac{p_{m-1}+p_{m}}{p_{m}}))=H(Y)+(P_{m-1}+p_m)\cdot\sum{p\cdot{log{\frac{1}{p}}}}=H(Y)+(P_{m-1}+p_m)\cdot{H(\frac{p_{m-1}}{p_{m-1}+p_{m}},\frac{p_{m}}{p_{m-1}+p_{m}})}.$$